# CONTROL CIRCUIT : Question Regarding Voltage and Resistance

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, control-system

[image: Exam Question]

I was wondering, whether my explanation was correct or not. I checked with online sources and they say I was incorrect, but I cannot understand how I am incorrect.

As the resistance increases, doesn't the voltage increase proportionally? 
So if the resistor value increase the voltage at POINT C will also increase??

Thanks!

Comment: Part (a) is asking for a voltage, not time. Look at the graph. Part (b) the resistor is part of an RC circuit. You want to know how to change the time it takes for the voltage at point C to drop to a certain amount. This should immediately tell you that you need to decrease the time constant.

Comment: @RobertStiffler  Hi, thanks for the clarification of the error in part (a) , however I was wondering whether my explanation was correct for part(b). And if it was not, then maybe you could help me understand where I went wrong.

Comment: going by the picture, apparently the input is the bottom end of the capacitor and the output is a resistor between point C and ground which feeds a capacitor and an some edge triggered logic.  this is perverse!

Comment: @Jasen  Hi, could you explain what you mean by your comment. I am not that proficient in electronics.

Comment: apparently the author of this question wasnt proficient either.

Comment: The picture is a bit goofy and it's not clear what is going on inside of the black box. I think that's the point. You do know that you have an RC circuit and the graph looks like a discharge curve. The time constant for an RC circuit is proportional to the resistance and capacitance, and smaller time constants means a quicker decay. You should conclude that a smaller resistance or capacitance will shorten the time delay.

Comment: @RobertStiffler as the voltage at point C is shown as apparently  proportional to the discharge rate of the capacitor a larger resistor will reduce the peak voltage at that point bringing it closer to the set point. potentially reducing the period.

Comment: using a high-pass filter for a delay element is perverse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

we've got a capacitor and a series resistor and then point c

we've got a graph of "voltage at point c" that looks like it might be  logarithmic.

from the text it can be understood that when voltage at point c drops low enough the deflector is activated. the deflector then operates autonomously for 2 seconds deploying and the retracts (presumably taking approximately another 2 seconds but that's not important)

we're told point C is connected to a voltage activated trigger

to have the deflector fully deployed at 3 seconds we need to delay for only 1 second as there are two seconds of delay inherent in the deflector.
that means deploy at 6V

to increase the delay by mofiying the external components the easiest answer is to increase the capacitance of the capacitor, this will make the discharge take longer (I'm assuming the capacitor sis charged to a fixed voltage - this seems like a reasonable assumption)

the effect of the resistor on the voltage at point C is more complicated.

assuming the bottom end of the capacitor is held at a constant voltage during the discharge. We aren't told this, but from the graph it seems likely, (and we aren't given any other point to measure voltage from!)
point C behaves somwwhat like a resistor to ground: the more current is flowing into it the higher the voltage.

looking carefully at the graph reveals that it is not exponetial decay.  in the first second the voltage halves, but in the next second it doesn't.
so point C isn't pure resistance to ground... looking even more closely, I am unable to fit any exponential curve to that graph, thus the terminal behind point C can't be treated as a fixed thevenin equivalent circuit.

The graph looks approimately hyperbolic, I can't immagine what circuitry or electrical behaviour behind terminal C would be required to get that effect.

Either this is a trick question, or it is very badly written.